# Datagridview wont sort on column click

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

My code using winforms is:

```
ctxTripStops = new DatabaseContextx();
ctxTripStops.TripStops.Where(p => p.TripId == id).Load();
bsTripStops.DataSource = ctxTripStops.TripStops.Local;
dgvSecondary.DataSource = bsTripStops;
```

I also have a bindingnavigator bound to the Datagridview.
Everything works OK- add, delete and edit in the grid updates the database on SaveChanges().  What doesn't work is clicking on a column header to sort the grid.  I know that you use ToBindingList() then it will sort but then I loose the add and delete functionallity. Is it possible to add the sorting capability?

Comment: did you set the property to allow sorting..?

Comment: If you mean the SortMode in each column, then yes.  As I said, it sorts OK if I add a ToBindingList() to the query.

Comment: personally I would bind the data to a DataTable and the sorting is handled for you

Comment: Why do you think using `ToBindingList()` will loose the add/delete functionality? In fact `ToBindingList` is specifically provided to be used for WF data binding.

Comment: How should I change the code to include ToBindingList()?  Everything Ive tried breaks add and delete ie doing a SaveChanges does not handle any added or deleted rows in the grid.

Comment: `bsTripStops.DataSource = ctxTripStops.TripStops.Local.ToBindingList();` should do. The returned `BindingList<T>` implementation will stay in sync with `DbSet<T>.Local` property.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing data locally use a data set. Drag and drop a dataset to the winform, then select untyped.  If you already have data inside the gridview you can easily add that data by :

```
DataSet DataSet1 = new dataset

dataset1.Tables.Add("Main");

foreach(DataGridViewColumn col in GridView.Columns)
{
    string name = col.Name.ToString();
    DataSet1.Tables["Main"].Columns.Add(name);
    DataSet1.AcceptChanges();
}

foreach(DataGridViewRow row in GridView.Rows)
{
    string value1 = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    string value2 = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    DataSet1.Tables["Main"].Rows.Add(value1,value2);
    DataSet1.AcceptChanges();

}
```

To save the dataset use this code:

```
string path = "path to where to save";
DataSet1.WriteXml(path,XmlWriteOption.WriteScheme);
```

to read dataset into program

```
string path = "path of saved xml";
Dataset1.ReadXml(path);

//Binds with DataGrid
DataGridView1.DataSource = DataSet1;
DataGridView1.DataMember = "Main";
DataGridView1.Update();
```

in order to for adding a new row manually you will need to make a     RowsAdded Event  if your using visual studio in properties click the lighting bolt and scroll down to RowsAdded and double click it.

```
DataGridView1_RowsAdded_Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet1.AcceptChanges();
}
```

you will do the same with Rows Deleted. By calling     DataSet1.AcceptChanges()
you are telling the program to keep current changes.

Comment: Using entity framework has nothing to do with data set.

Comment: It doesn't matter if he is using entity FrameWork, .Net FrameWork, WinForms will use a DataSet the Same way.  Correct me if I am Wrong? Creating the dataset for use, would be doing the same as Writing his Data to a List, But Allows him to combine Data From several BindingSources if Told to do so.

Comment: Using `DataSet` along with the Entity Framework is wrong. The user is binding the `DataGridView` to `context.DbSet.Local` and wants to make the `DataGridView` sortable. The correct answer has been given by Ivan Stoev in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47561380/datagridview-wont-sort-on-column-click/47563072?noredirect=1#comment82096435_47561380).

Comment: you Can also use the Binding source to Fill the DataSet, Then Everytime information is Add, upon Calling the DataSet.AcceptChanges(), If im not mistaken should update the Datasource from which the data was pulled.

Comment: The question is not about `DataSet`! It's about Entity Framework, `DbContext` and `DbSet`!

Comment: dbSet is a dataSet, thus dataset1.Fill(ctxTripStops.TripStops.Local);  would also do the exact same thing. Thus using the Entity Framework to fill the grid. Calling to BindingList(); is one way, dataset another, dataTable another. there is more than one Correct Answer. The Question was getting the datagridview to sort, using the entity FrameWork, the Coding i provided was how to use A database. Im sorry i didnt change my answer to directly fit his coding.

Comment: Oh man! `DbSet` has nothing to do with `DataSet`. Your answer is not relevant to the question. He is not looking for a way of filling DGV, he is asking specifically about EF and DGV.